# Best method to compress large dataset features

Tags: python, compression, hdf5

10TB featurs which stored on aws s3 bucket.
in order to decrease costs , we are looking for a loseless compression method for those features (current features are images but it can changed between projects)

I heard about hdf5, but is it the best method nowadays?
Can the the extraction be paralleled?

Comment: what type of images do you have? Usually JPG can gives smaller size of file - but it is not loseless. `WebP` can also better compress and is loseless. And all this depend of content of image. Some uses special tools or portals like [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/) to create small files with images

Comment: How is this related to Python or DVC?

Comment: zpaq features deduplication, multithreaded compression and decompression and various modes and the possiblity to implement custom codec, or try lz4+lzma